# Simple css container do not align elements as it should

Tags: html, css

I have a simple css div with some styling from bootstrap and this is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/w9gyc0t5/

This is the code

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>
    <h5 class="text-danger"><b>General</b></h5>
    <h5 class="text-danger float-right"><b>General</b></h5>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I was expecting the H5 element to align perfectly with the element that has been floated right. I know i could move the element floated right to align with the one on the left, but i want to know what is causing this behavior and are there new css innovations such as flex box that solves this problem.

Comment: make the float element the first one and not the second in the html code

Comment: Hmm, that works, but why?

Comment: h5 is already full width so the float will start *floating* under it. If you want the first h5 to float around, you need to make the float before .. well, you don't need to it this way, consider flexbox: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: You can also drop float  and use built-in BS4  classes https://jsfiddle.net/wz52qb9n/ If you want to use float, you'll have to dig inside old tutorials to find out about its behavior and sides effects ;).

Comment: Adding margins to row is plumbing gone too far.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to remove the class **float-right** from second `<h5>` and put in on the first `<h5>` like this:

```
 <div>
     <h5 class="text-danger float-right"><b>General</b></h5>
     <h5 class="text-danger"><b>General</b></h5>
 </div>
```

Here is the fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/6h20bwqc/3/

**N.B.** But **FlexBox** is recommended as it is a modern and clean solution.

Just add `class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"` to the wrapper div and remove `float-right` for a flex-box solution:

Here is Fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/6h20bwqc/4/